# Сколько в среднем один модератор обрабатывает тревог в день?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги

Сколько в среднем один модератор обрабатывает тревог в день?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В день обычно несколько десятков тревог. Но не все модераторы постоянно мониторят сайт. Так что сложно в среднем сказать, сколько в день обрабатывает модератор, т.к. в различные дни/недели/месяцы эти числа меняются.

Если онлайн только один модератор, то 20-40 тревог в день обрабатывает.

Comment: Получается что мои тревоги могут быть 25% — 50%.20 - 40 тревог в день, а у меня десять(правда не все обработаны)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica да, есть у нас несколько любителей тревог (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Я в их числе (любителей тревог)?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica в последнее время да)

Comment: А кто еще(или военная тайна)?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica не могу такое разглашать.

Comment: Модератор видит, кто ставит тревогу?

Comment: @nomnoms12 конечно ╮(︶▽︶)╭

Comment: _есть у нас несколько любителей тревог_ - нужен бадж **Тревожное расстройство личности**! Страна должна знать своих героев, на ком все держится)

Comment: @mkkik не все эти участники тревогают по делу)

Comment: @mkkik Уже есть: прокурор(500 тревог) и участковый(80 тревог).

Comment: А проверки внимательности для модераторов есть?

Comment: @maestro нет такого.